# To specify $a,b,k$ in $a\cos(kx)+b$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

If we have known that $f(x)=a\cos(kx)+b$ for some $
f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb C$,
is there a method of choosing finite $(x,f(x))$ to know what $a,b,k$ are?

Comment: How about k in the formula?

Comment: Not quite.  You can always change $k$ to $-k$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael You're absolutely right.

Comment: what I mean is : if there is no k, because you can determine cosx, a and b are easy to be determind. But in this case, cos x cannot be determined because of the existence of k.

Comment: @SteveCheng鄭宗弘 Looks like I was wrong. As Robert says, the function $f(x)=a\cos(kx)+b$ equals to the function $g(x)=a\cos ((-k)x)+b$ and so you can never determine $k$.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Generally speaking you have 3 unknowns therefore you need at leadst 3 equations therefore you need at least 3 points on the graph. However you might not be able to solve the equations analytically.

Comment: is there a way to determine $f$ but not $k$?

Answer (score 2):

Even if you require $k>0$ to avoid the sign ambiguity, there will be trouble.  After eliminating $a$ and $b$ from the equations $f(x_1) = y_1$, $f(x_2) = y_2$, $f(x_3) = y_3$ you get

$$ (y_2 - y_3) \cos(k x_1) + (y_3 - y_1) \cos(k x_2) + (y_1 - y_2) \cos(k x_3) = 0 $$

from which you want to determine $k$.  However, the left side will usually be $0$ for infinitely many $k$. The exceptions are when one of the $x_i$, let's say $x_1$, is $0$, and $y_3-y_1$ and $y_1-y_2$ have the same sign, in which case the only way to satisfy the equation is for $\cos(k x_1)$ and $\cos(k x_2)$ to both be $1$, and therefore (if $x_1/x_2$ is irrational) $k = 0$.

Thus if the answer happens to be $k = 0$ you can choose the $x_i$ and $y_i$ to prove that, but if the correct $k$ is nonzero you can't determine it.